# Swift - change UICollectionViewCell size

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm struggling to change the size of my `UICollectionViewCell` programmatically.

I've tried this:

```swift
let columnLayout = FlowLayout(
        itemSize: CGSize(width: 150, height: 150),
        minimumInteritemSpacing: 10,
        minimumLineSpacing: 10,
        sectionInset: UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 20, bottom: 10, right: 20))
```

But that doesn't work for me. Do I have to call this somewhere?

Comment: how do you use `columnLayout`

Comment: i actually don't really use it :D thats my problem, I don't really know where I should use it

Comment: What is the layout you are trying to achieve and what is the result you're getting?

Comment: i simply want a 2 x X layout where each cell is 150x150

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout = columnLayout
```

inside `viewDidLoad`

```
lazy var columnLayout:FlowLayout = {
   return FlowLayout(itemSize: CGSize(width:(self.view.frame.width - 40) / 2, height: 150),
    minimumInteritemSpacing: 10,
    minimumLineSpacing: 10,
    sectionInset: UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 20, bottom: 10, right: 20)) 
}()
```

Comment: "Ambiguous reference to member `collectionView(_:numerOfItemsInSection:)`

Comment: the cells are left-alligned right now. Do you know how I can center them?

Comment: try `CGSize(width:(self.view.frame.width - 40) / 2, height: 150)` assuming collection width is screen width or as you set it

Comment: inside `columnsLayout` ??